# 960 grid and compass

Tags: css, compass-sass, 960.gs

I'm new to using compass/sass and I've installed a [960 plugin](https://github.com/nextmat/compass-960-plugin). So far so good.

The only thing is I'm using the more recent .scss syntax and when I try to set my container by:

```
.container {
    +grid-container;
}
```

I am getting a compile error of:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "   +grid-container": expected "{", was ";"
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay here it is.

First declare the amount of columns to use:

```
$ninesixty-columns: 12;
```

then declare your "container" if you use one:

```
.container {
    @include grid-container;
}
```

Then just give the amounts:

```
.main {
    @include grid(9);
    @include alpha;
    }
.sidebar {
    @include grid(3);
    @include omega;
}
```